# how to avoid applying Token for the non TokenRelay pages at spring security

Tags: spring-security, token, spring-security-oauth2

I am using Spring Cloud Starter Security and Spring Boot Starter Ouath2 Client in my Reactive application and made my configurations at application.yml as you will see below.

It applies Token perfectly for the pages that has TokenRelay but the problem is **I have to configure that it should not apply Token for the pages that has no TokenRelay**. How I can success it ?
Could you please help me find out that issue ? You can find my codes below.

**pom.xml**

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

**application.yml**

```
 routes:
    - id: securedApp
      uri: http://localhost:51687
      predicates:
        - Path=/keycloak-oidc-code/**
      filters:
        - TokenRelay=
        - RemoveRequestHeader=Cookie
  filter:
    # Removes Expect Header that send to the services
    remove-hop-by-hop:
      headers:
        - expect
security:
  basic:
    enable: false
  ignored: /**
oauth2:
  client:
    registration:
      sample-authorization-code:
        id: MyApplication
        client-id: MyApplication
        client-secret:f607d7c5-991d-4605-843f-330f419ed143
        client-name: SecondApplication
        provider: keycloak
        redirect-uri: '{baseUrl}/login/oauth2/code/{registrationId}'
        authorization-grant-type: authorization_code
        client-authentication-method: post
        scope: openid, address, fun
    provider:
        keycloak:
        issuer-uri: http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/MyApplication
server:
  port: 8001
```

SecurityConfig.java

```
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig
{

 @Bean
 SecurityWebFilterChain springSecurityFilterChain( ServerHttpSecurity http ) throws Exception
{


    return http.authorizeExchange().matchers( EndpointRequest.to( InfoEndpoint.class, HealthEndpoint.class)).permitAll().anyExchange().authenticated().and().oauth2Login().and().build();


}
```

}

Comment: @denizg hello deniz sorry i forgot to mark your answer as approved. İ approved it thanks for your precious helps

Comment: But anyway this question still has no answer. İ would appreciate if someone can help me

Comment: do you have any repository or test-case about applying token for the url's which has no TokenRelay= filter ? because you mentioned "it should not apply Token for the pages that has no TokenRelay" but basically if you dont use TokenRelay= filter in route, it doesnt apply when downstream.

Comment: hi deniz. yes I do for the link : "http://localhost:61307/nonTestReplayApplication/rest/apps/appname/models/module1/v/1.0.0/mm1"  the application which starts with nonTestReplayApplication should not apply Token. how I can provide that ? I am using TokenRelay with no parameter I should apply TokenRelay = filter or do I have to include any additional parameter for that?

Comment: i cant really understand your question. anladığım kadarıyla elinde 3 uygulama var. birisi gateway, birisi secured app, birisi de non-secured app. gateway'den non-secured app'e istek gittiğinde access token üzerinden herhangi bir kontrol işlemi yapılmasın istiyorsun değil mi? bu durumda non-secured app'in security configuration'ını sağla.

Comment: deniz selam.aynen dediğin gibi. 3 uygulamadan gateway, secured-app da herhangi bir problem yok. ancak non-secured uygulamam da token istiyor. non-secured uygulamamın token istememesini sağlamam gerekiyor. bunun için acaba Application.yaml de TokenRelay konfigürasyonunda "=" olarak sağladım , bir değişiklik mi yapmam gerekicek ? ya da buna özel bir TokenAuthenticationFilter mı yazmam gerekicek? Daha önce web uygulamalar için yazılmış TokenAuthenticationFilter gözlemledim ama reactive uygulamalar için yazılmış böyle bir uygulama bulamadım ondan sormak istedim.Açıkçası çıkmazdayım şu anda

Comment: bu durumda senin olayın tokenrelay= ile ilgili değil, non-secured uygulamanın konfigurasyonu ile alakalı. non-secured uygulaman token istiyorsa eğer, resourceserver ayarını kaldırmalısın. soruyu, non-secured uygulamanın kodlarını ekleyerek güncellersen  daha detaylı yardım edebilirim.

Comment: deniz selam. nonsecure uygulamamda EnableResourceServer ya da resourceserver ayar yok. bildiğim kadarıyla EnableResourceServer ekleyince resourceserver ayarı yapılıyor. NonSecured uygulamam şu anda mocklanmış bir test uygulaması şeklimde yazdım. Ama bire bir.o uygulama gibi davranıyor. Buna rağmen ne yazık ki token istiyor herhangi bir ayarlamam bulmamama rağmen. Bu mümkün mü ? Mesela pom.xml içerisinden spring-cloud-starter-security i dahil ettiğimde testler 200 yerine 302 alırken bu dependency kaldırdığımda testler 200 gelmekte. spring-cloud-starter-security token istiyor gibi gözüküyor

Comment: "Mesela pom.xml içerisinden spring-cloud-starter-security i dahil ettiğimde". non-secured app'den bahsediyorsun değil mi burada?

Comment: DeniZ selam ne yazık ki gateway uygulamasından bahsediyorum. Gateway uygulamasında non secured app ı mocklayıp non secured app testlerini calıstırdıgımda 200 yerine 302 alıyorum. Öncesinde pom a eklemeden önce 200 alıyordu buradan non secured app ın da token istediği sonucunu cıkardım ki direk oauth2 ye gönderdi.umarım anlatmayı basarabilmişimdir.önerilerini rica ederim.cok tesekkurler

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210486/discussion-between-denizg-and-tonyukuk).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is missing a point. You need to add new route for non-secured app to application.yml and you have to permit that route in security configuration that you mentioned at SecurityConfig.java.

application.yml

```
routes:
- id: testMyApplication
  uri: localhost:61307
  predicates:
  - Path=/myApplication/**
```

SecurityConfig.java

```
return http.authorizeExchange().pathMatchers( "/myApplication/**"").
permitAll().anyExchange().authenticated().and().oauth2Login().and().build();
```